# Airflow SQL Server Connection -Adaptive Server connection failed

Tags: python, airflow

i am currently working on "Astronomer Runtime 5.0.6 based on Airflow 2.3.3+astro.1" and trying to connect MS SQL Server 2019 in Airflow Connection and I am getting the following error after giving the correct hostname and port name:

```
(20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (5e65e6546565r)\n')
```

Here are my settings in airflow UI -

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue and I think it's related to the MSSQL firewall

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the authentication type from Windows to SQL Server, enable SA login and then fill in both fields "Login" and "Password" in the airflow connection settings
[Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16)